# I'm trying to make a function that returns the Nth Fibonacci number with recursion & memoization. I can't understand why it keeps outputing a function

Tags: javascript, recursion, fibonacci, memoization

I am having a hard time understanding why my function keeps outputting the function definition. I tried to solve it using memorization and recursion without creating an inner function, but without an inner function to separate the monetization object, my inner object just kept getting reset to an empty object. Here is that code...

```
function fib(n) {
    // create a memoization object
  let memo = {};
  // base case 1: if n=0, return 0
  if (n===0) return 0;
  // base case 2: if n=1, return 1
  if (n===1) return 1;
  // base case 3: if there is a property on the memo object for n, return that property value
  if(memo[n]) return memo[n];
  // recursive case: memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
  memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
  // return memo[n]
   return memo[n];
 }
```

Here the function works but makes no use of the monetization object. So I tried creating an inner function to create a closure...

```
function fib() {
    // create a memoization object
  let memo = {};
  // create an inner function
  function inner(n) {
    // base case 1: if n=0, return 0
    if (n===0) return 0;
    // base case 2: if n=1, return 1
    if (n===1) return 1;
    // base case 3: if there is a property on the memo object for n, return that property value
    if(memo[n]) return memo[n];
    // recursive case: memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2)
    memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
    // return memo[n]
    return memo[n];
  }
  // return the inner function
  return inner;
}

// To check if you've completed the challenge, uncomment this code!
let innerFib = fib()
console.log(innerFib(1)); // -> 1
console.log(innerFib(2)); // -> 1
console.log(innerFib(7)); // -> 13
```

For some reason the first test case outputs '1', but all the others output the actual function definition like this...

```
1
'function inner(n) { // base case 1: if n=0, return 0 if (n===0) return 0; // base case 2: if n=1, return 1 if (n===1) return 1; // base case 3: if there is a property on the memo object for n, return that property value if(memo[n]) return memo[n]; // recursive case: memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); // return memo[n] return memo[n]; }function inner(n) { // base case 1: if n=0, return 0 if (n===0) return 0; // base case 2: if n=1, return 1 if (n===1) return 1; // base case 3: if there is a property on the memo object for n, return that property value if(memo[n]) return memo[n]; // recursive case: memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); // return memo[n] return memo[n]; }'
'function inner(n) { // base case 1: if n=0, return 0 if (n===0) return 0; // base case 2: if n=1, return 1 if (n===1) return 1; // base case 3: if there is a property on the memo object for n, return that property value if(memo[n]) return memo[n]; // recursive case: memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); // return memo[n] return memo[n]; }function inner(n) { // base case 1: if n=0, return 0 if (n===0) return 0; // base case 2: if n=1, return 1 if (n===1) return 1; // base case 3: if there is a property on the memo object for n, return that property value if(memo[n]) return memo[n]; // recursive case: memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2) memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2); // return memo[n] return memo[n]; }'
```

I have a feeling I may just be calling the function incorrectly with labeling it and trying to use currying (if that is the right term...)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```js
memo[n] = fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
```

it should be

```js
memo[n] = inner(n-1) + inner(n-2);
```